# Accidentally allowed IntelliJ to install new typescript plugin and after that typescript hints and eslint stopped working on Mac

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, plugins, tslint

Accidentally allowed IntelliJ to install new typescript plugin and after that typescript hints and tslint stopped working on Mac. Cannot find out what the plugin was. Would like to uninstall it.
Here's how project files look like now (with T-icon upfront):
[image]

In the list of plugins I can see only 'JavaScript and TypeScript' which I think should be there. TSLint plugin is enabled. Would appreciate any advice on how I could roll back IntelliJ settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Preferences > Plugins and look in the Installed tab, you'll be able to see all the installed plugins.
You'll notice that some of the plugins will say that they are "bundled" (or, come with the IDE). Check the ones that are not bundled (i.e. which you have installed additionally) and disable them one by one until you find the one responsible for this behaviour. Good luck!